# Draw vertical line down aligned equation

Tags: align, line

How do I go about drawing a line vertically down aligned equations like this:

[image]

I attempted using a tabular environment but some of the spacing is too much.

This is what I have so far:

**CODE**

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} 


\begin{document}
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{ccc|ll|ll|l|ll|l}
    U1    & =     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X1} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
    U2    & =     & X2    &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
    U3    & =     & X3    & +     & X1    &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  \\
          & =     &       &       &       & +     & X2    & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  \\
    Un    & =     & Xn    &       &       &       &       & …     & +     & Xn-1  &  \\
    Sn    & =     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & Xn \\
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put a bunch of `[b]`ottom-`aligned` constructions next to one another, separated by a `\vrule`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{aligned}[b]
    U_1 &= X_1 \\
    U_2 &= X_2 \\
    U_3 &= X_3 \\
    \\ \\
    U_n &= X_n \\
      S &= \mathstrut
  \end{aligned}
  {\vrule\begin{aligned}[b]
    \mathstrut \\ {}+ X'_1 \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut
  \end{aligned}}
  {\vrule\begin{aligned}[b]
    \mathstrut \\ {}+ X'_2 \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut
  \end{aligned}}
  {\vrule\begin{aligned}[b]
    \mathstrut \\ {}+ X'_3 \\ \mathstrut \\ \mathstrut
  \end{aligned}}
  {\vrule\begin{aligned}[b]
    \mathstrut \\ \quad\cdots\quad \\ \mathstrut
  \end{aligned}}
  {\vrule\begin{aligned}[b]
    \mathstrut \\ {}+ X'_{n-1}
  \end{aligned}}
\]

\end{document}
```

The `\vrule`s are grouped with an `aligned` that has a blank top row (using `\mathstrut`). The `\vrule` will stretch the vertical length of the construction by default.

Answer (score 4):

The `blkarray` package provides a convenient means to produce aligned (and non-aligned) material with separators spanning different rows, inside a maths environment (such as align). This is done by adding 'blocks' with different column specifications to a 'blockarray' environment defined by the package. In the below code, I use one block per row, simply adding an extra column line for each successive row (note that each block must still have the same number of total columns, albeit empty ones):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 \begin{blockarray}{cccccc}
  \begin{block}{cccccc}
    U_1=X_1&&&&&\\ % Row 1
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}{c|ccccc}
    U_2=X_1&&&&&\\ % Row 2
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}{c|c|cccc}
    U_3=X_3&+X_1'&&&&\\  % Row 3
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}{c|c|c|ccc}
    &&+X_2'&&&\\ % Row 4
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}{c|c|c|c|cc}
   &&&&&\\ % Row 5
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
    U_n=X_n &&&\ldots&+X_{n-1}'&\\ % Row 6
  \end{block}
  \begin{block}{c|c|c|c|c|c}
    s=\phantom{x}&&&&&+X_n'\\ % Row 7
  \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a proposition, with `tabular`replaced by `array`, a smaller value for `arraycolsep` and some improvements:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{makebox}


\begin{document}

% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering \setlength{\arraycolsep}{3pt}
  \caption{Add caption}\[
    \begin{array}{c@{{}={}}c|ll|ll|l|ll|l}
    U_1 & X_1 \\
    U_2 & X_2 & \\
    U_3 & X_3 & + & X_1 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\makebox*{$U_3$}{ $ \smash[t]{\vdots} $\hspace{1.5em}}} & \smash[t]{\vdots} & & & + & X_2 \\
    U_n & X_n & & & & & \cdots & + & X_{n-1} \\
    S_n & & & & & & & & & X_n \\
    \end{array} \]%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Unrelated*: needless to load `masfonts` when you load `amssymb`: the latter package already loads it.

Comment: Note that the spacing would be slightly different, see [math mode - Match spacing of align in array environment - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7728/match-spacing-of-align-in-array-environment)

Answer (score 2):

Some spacing is too much? Reduce it.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts} 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabular}{c@{\ }c@{}c|l@{\ }l|l@{\ }l|l|l@{\ }l|l}
    U1    & =     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{X1} &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
    U2    & =     & X2    &       & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{r}{} &  \\
    U3    & =     & X3    & +     & X1    &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  \\
          & =     &       &       &       & +     & X2    & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &       & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} &  \\
    Un    & =     & Xn    &       &       &       &       & …     & +     & Xn-1  &  \\
    Sn    & =     &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       & Xn \\
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please watch out `X1` and `X2 ` vertical alignment.